Meta Quest 3 access files between users?
Using ADB or other methods, is there a way to access the secondary account's files?
The Meta Quest Developer Hub is able to download files in the File Manager tab on Windows, which makes me think, there must be a way to access the folders Pictures, etc. for the secondary user to copy and paste into directly from the computer or to possibly transfer between users without wasting bandwidth.
Filtered with Wireshark filtered by the IP and port of the Meta Quest, it is picking up some shell commands, although I'm not even sure where to begin, as in a matter of seconds, it is over a thousand packets. 1772 packets 261 contain the word "shell" within a few seconds. I tried to force it to redownload a small picture from the file manager tab. Perhaps the process is not a plain text command as some packets I'm not understanding.

Does "Meta Quest Developer Hub" require adb? If yes you can simply sniff the adb commands it executes by using Wireshark on the localhost interface and filter tcp port 5037. The adb command is included as plain text in the adb traffic.

@Robert filtered with wireshark filtered by the ip and port of the meta quest, it is picking up some shell commands although I'm not even sure where to begin as in a matter of seconds it is over a thousand packets. 1772 packets 261 contain the word "shell" within the few seconds I tried to force it to redownload a small picture from the file manager tab. Perhaps the process is not a plain text command as some packets I'm not understanding.
